# Inverse Square Law's effect on solar panels

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, reflection, solar-cells

Hey I'm doing an experiment for school and I'm trying to investigate how the distance of a light source affects the output of a solar panel and I've faced a few problems since i'm trying to include the Inverse Square Law in my experiments.
I used a bed side lamp with a 20W bulb and a radioshack 1W solar panel.
I propped the lamp on a stool and stood the solar panel on a dresser. I wired a multimeter to the solar panel with 20V DC setting. Heres my data table (http://prntscr.com/ilfzmi). As you can see it does not follow the Inverse Square Law as I expected but the voltage does decrease. I tried measuring the current but I think my multimeter does not work right because it shows 0 Amps even if I add a resistor/load to the solar panel.
I think the voltage didn't decrease as rapidly because the lamp had a sort of reflector hood around the light bulb (like this http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0093813_PE231404_S5.JPG (this is exact lamp i used)), can anyone tell me what I've done wrong, how to improve this experiment and if the panel should even be following the Inverse Square Law.

Comment: It is the _current_ (short-circuit current) that is proportional to light intensity.

Comment: Not sure about the spatial uniformity of the light over the area of the solar panel with the reflector on. Reflectors can cause big variations in the local light intensity over a small area. I think that just using a bare light bulb would ensure better spatial uniformity of the light. Also, as Pieter pointed out, you're assuming that the panel's voltage is a directly proportional to the total light flux on the panel.

Comment: Can you explain why the voltage does not undergo the inverse square law but the current does?

Comment: @MazenMustafa - I think that the point is that the current of a solar panel (into a very low resistance) is proportional to the total light flux on the panel, whereas the voltage is not. A convenient way of thinking of it is that an absorbed photon creates an electron-hole pair which creates an incremental amount of current.

Comment: why voltage doesn't change:  If there are sufficient photons hitting the panel, it will reach the panel's MANUFACTURER specified voltage.  That's just how they work.  This is why the current will APPEAR to be proportial (inverse square) to distance.  In fact it's the POWER (energy per unit time), that is proportional.  (P=I*V   ... when V is constant: if P changes, current must change)